# How to hide/show some form in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

The home page of my application has a panel where the user can login to my website.
This is the login form that appears in the home page:

```
<%= form_for(:session, :url => sessions_path) do |f| %>
<table>
<tr>
<th><h2>Login</h2></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field">
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="actions">
<%= f.submit "Entrar" %>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<p>New user? <%= link_to "Registrate ahora!", signup_path%></p>
```

And the sign up form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Sign up</th>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td class="field">
<%=f.label :email%><br />
<%=f.text_field :email%>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field">
<%=f.label :password, "Contraseña"%><br />
<%=f.password_field :password%>         
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="field">
<%=f.label :password_confirmation,"Confirmar Contraseña"%><br />
<%=f.password_field :password_confirmation%>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="actions">
<%=f.submit "Registrate"%>
</td>
</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
```

I want to show the sign up form on the home page and hide the login form when the user presses the "new user?" button without redirecting the user to another page (signup_path) and also implement a button in the sign up form that redirects the user to the sign in form on the same home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Registrate ahora!", signup_path, :class => "new-user-link"%>
```

in jquery

```
$(".new-user-link").click(function(){
    $(<sign up form class>).show();
    return false;
}
```